# Django ForeignKey for Imported Table Data

Tags: django, import, foreign-keys

I have two tables, School and Scores, which have a column 'psid' in common. I am importing the data from each table into my app. I want to link the two tables together through a ForeignKey (there can be multiple Scores for one School).

Currently my models.py looks like this:

```
class School(models.Model):
    psid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Score(models.Model):
    psid = models.ForeignKey(School, max_length=5, db_column='psid')
    scores = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
```

Do I need an additional field in Scores so that I can both import the psid column from the original table AND have a ForeignKey field that links Scores and School together through the 'psid' column?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused a bit, do you wish to fetch the related school object psid value or have another independent field for each Score object named psid which is unrelated to the school psid column (btw class names should not be plural)?

Comment: Hi yuvi, Yes Score should be singular. I edited the question to fix that. My goal is to be able to fetch the school object with the psid value. In my template, I display the scores for each school.

Comment: Why do you think you need another field?

Comment: fetching related models and their information is a very basic part of the django ORM, and I suggest you open up a `manage.py shell` and learn [how to execute simple queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/queries/). I also suggest you go over the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial01/) at least once (if you haven't already)

Comment: @DanielRoseman I was primarily concerned that I was making a mistake in my initial setup (which based on your replies I'm not). Using db_column in Score it should be the case that I can match up the two tables through the psid ForeignKey? When I display Score information for a School in my template the psid matching is off, ie. it will show Scores for the wrong School. That could be related to my views or template I suppose. I'll try again later with a more specific question related to that. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django models handle linking the tables behind the scenes for the most part.  The `ForeignKey` field type is enough to accomplish this, then you just have to use the ORM to join the tables in a query.  Here is how I would set up your tables based on my best interpretation of what you are looking for:

```
from django.db import models


class School(models.Model):
    psid = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=5)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{0} ({1})".format(self.psid, self.city)


class Score(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, null=False, db_column="psid")
    score = models.IntegerField()

    def __unicode__(sefl):
        return u"Score({0}, {1})".format(self.school.psid, self.score)
```

Then to test your models out:

```
$ ./manage.py syncdb
$ ./manage.py shell
>>> from schools.models import School, Score
>>> school1 = School(psid="S1", city="Springfield")
>>> school1
S1 (Springfield)
>>> school1.save()
>>> School.objects.get(psid="S1")
S1 (Springfield)
>>> school2 = School(psid="S2", city="Springfield")
>>> school2.save()
>>> score1 = Score(school=school1, score=3)
>>> score1
Score(S1, 3)
>>> score1.school.psid
S1
>>> score2 = Score(school=school1, score=2)
>>> score3 = Score(school=school2, score=5)
>>> score1.save()
>>> score2.save()
>>> score3.save()
>>> school1.score_set.all()
[Score(S1, 3), Score(S1, 2)]
>>> school2.score_set.all()
[Score(S2, 5)]
>>> Score.objects.all()
[Score(S1, 3), Score(S1, 2), Score(S2, 5)] 
>>> Score.objects.filter(school__psid="S1")
[Score(S1, 3), Score(S1, 2)]
```

I hope that helps you out.

Comment: This is VERY helpful. I worked through shell code several times and that solidified things for me. Hopefully it will for others as well.

Comment: For some reason I was not "trusting" that the ForeignKey would work when I mass imported data for the two tables and I wasn't comfortable on my own doing the shell as you showed. So I thought I still needed to have 'psid' in both tables. Simply setting 'psid' as 'score' as you suggested (and Django docs advise) is the way to go. Thanks again for taking the time to elucidate this.